# C# WFA VS - speed up alternative in-game clock connected to local time DateTime.Now

Tags: javascript, c#, visual-studio, datetime

so i've found some code, and applied to my needs, and it seems to work, but now i need to do the same stuff in C# (for and app) or to do an app for windows in javascript. any help? here's the code:

```js
const speed = 7; // how many times faster than real time
    let clockDiv = document.querySelector("#clock");
    let gameStartTime = 10800000; // game-milliseconds;
    let realStartTime = Date.now(); // real milliseconds

    let timerId = setInterval(function() {
      let gameTime = gameStartTime + Date.now() * speed;
      let sec = Math.floor(gameTime / 1000) % 60;
      let min = Math.floor(gameTime / 60000) % 60;
      let hour = Math.floor(gameTime / 3600000) % 24;
      // output in hh:mm:ss format:
      clockDiv.textContent = `${hour}:${min}:${sec}`.replace(/\b\d\b/g, "0$&");
    }, 50);
```

```html
<div id="clock" style="font-size:40pt;"></div>
```

Comment: Help with what? You have code that "seems to work" in javascript, so are you just asking for someone to port it to C# for you? If so, you need to have a go yourself and ask for assistance if you have issues.

Comment: thanks. for future, shall i add an answer here, and edit the initial post with some C# code, or create a new one? if that's not bother for you to answer. i did try, but apparently DateTime.Now is not giving the same data as in javascript.

Comment: I have made an answer. If you don't mind, you could click '✔' to mark my reply as the accepted answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

## C# Winform:

### MainDesign:

Control required:

1. Label*1
2. Timer*1

[image]

Timer:

[image]
[image]

### Code:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public static long currentTimeMillis()
        {
            return (System.DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks - Jan1st1970Ms) / 10000;
        }
        private static long Jan1st1970Ms = new System.DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, System.DateTimeKind.Utc).Ticks;
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            const int speed = 7;
            int gameStartTime = 10800000;
            Double realStartTime = currentTimeMillis();
            var gameTime = gameStartTime + realStartTime * speed;
            var sec = Math.Floor(gameTime / 1000) % 60;
            var min = Math.Floor(gameTime / 60000) % 60;
            var hour = Math.Floor(gameTime / 3600000) % 24;
            label1.Text = string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", hour, min, sec);
        }
    }
}
```

### Output:

[image]

Comment: May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer? I am glad to help if you have any others questions.